# App crashing when opening my fragment which contains a recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, fragment

Hey Guys i am relativly new to android development and working on my first project. I followed some YouTube tutorials like [this one,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m-Ve-BAYe0&t=298s) to implement a Recyclerview in a fragment. The data for the item is read from a SQLite Database. Before inserting the testdata my App opens and does not crash but as soon as i have inserted one row of data the app instantly crashes when i try to open that fragment.I hope you can help me and sorry for the long apendix.

```
2020-12-02 22:03:58.259 26079-26079/com.example.moneymanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.moneymanager, PID: 26079
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.moneymanager:layout/transaction_list_item: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.moneymanager:layout/transaction_list_item: Error inflating class Linearlayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.example.moneymanager:layout/transaction_list_item: Error inflating class Linearlayout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Linearlayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:913)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:930)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:950)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.example.moneymanager.TransactionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TransactionAdapter.kt:31)
        at com.example.moneymanager.TransactionAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TransactionAdapter.kt:13)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
2020-12-02 22:03:58.260 26079-26079/com.example.moneymanager E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:786)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2810)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1930)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7988)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1154)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:977)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1139)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Linearlayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.moneymanager-r4ktffjKddVGd51sWsQfMg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.moneymanager-r4ktffjKddVGd51sWsQfMg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 75 more
2020-12-02 22:03:58.300 26079-26079/com.example.moneymanager I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26079 SIG: 9
```

This is my Adapter class:\

```
     class TransactionAdapter(var mContext: Context, var mCursor: Cursor) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionAdapter.TransactionViewHolder>() { // this line is mentioned in the 
    error --> line 13
    
        lateinit var mData:List<ListItem>
    
        class TransactionViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            val amountText:     TextView
            val dateText:       TextView
            val categorieText:  TextView
    
            init {
                amountText      = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount)
                dateText        = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)
                categorieText   = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCategorie)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TransactionViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_item, parent, false) // also this 
    line is mentioned --> line 31
            return TransactionViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TransactionViewHolder, position: Int) {
            if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                return
            }
            val amount: String      = 
     mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT))
            val date: String        = 
     mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_CREATEDAT))
            val categorie: String   = 
     mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIE))
            holder.amountText.text  = amount
            holder.dateText.text    = date.toString()
            holder.categorieText.text = categorie
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return mCursor.getCount()
        }
    
        fun swapCursor(newCursor: Cursor) {
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.close()
            }
            mCursor = newCursor
            if (newCursor != null) {
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- this is my Fragment class:
    class ListFragment:Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list) {
    
        private lateinit var transactionDB: SQLiteDatabase
        private lateinit var adapter:TransactionAdapter
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            val dbHelper = TransactionDBHelper(activity)
            transactionDB = dbHelper.writableDatabase
        }
    
        private fun addTransactionItem(){
            transactionDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO transactionList (type, amount, categorie, createdAt) 
        VALUES('r', 10, 'test', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
            adapter.swapCursor(getAllItems())
        }
    
        private fun getAllItems(): Cursor {
            return transactionDB!!.query(
                    TransactionList.TransactionEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    TransactionList.TransactionEntry.COLUMN_CREATEDAT + " DESC")
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
    
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
            val rvRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvRecyclerView)
            rvRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = TransactionAdapter(activity!!, getAllItems())
            rvRecyclerView.adapter = this.adapter
    
            addTransactionItem() // inserting one row of test data
    
            return view
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. The name of the layout is `LinearLayout` with two capital `L`s, not `Linearlayout`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your layout file: the second "L" in `LinearLayout` should be capitalized but you have it lowercase. Replace `<Linearlayout ...>` with `<LinearLayout ...>`. You'll also have to fix the closing tag.

Comment: thanks, after hours of fixing my code i didnt realized that :D